# Finding The Average Of The Rows In A HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, average

I'm currently working on a project where I need to find the average of certain rows in a HTML table that'll update automatically when ever a value is changed.  I don't have a clue where to start as we were given this assignment and just told to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript without any prior knowledge so sorry if this question is basic.  I need to average value to be placed where the " appears on each row that contains them beside each other.

```
<table id="gradeTable"> <!Table>
<thead>
<tr id="Header">
    <th>Student Name:</th>
    <th>Student Number:</th>
    <th>Assignment 1 %:</th>
    <th>Assignment 2 %:</th>
    <th>Assignment 3 %:</th>
    <th>Assignment 4 %:</th>
    <th>Assignment 5 %:</th>
    <th>Final Grade %:</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tbody> 

<tr>
    <td id="Iden">Student A</td>
    <td id="Iden">172300</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td id="Final"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td id="Iden">Student B</td>
    <td id="Iden">172301</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td id="Final"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td id="Iden">Student C</td>
    <td id="Iden">172302</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);"/></td>
    <td id="Final"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [so] is not a programming school. I don't understand schools that give assignments without teaching the material, but that's your problem, not ours.

Comment: Hi Conor, please read about how to ask with [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you have a specific piece of code that is not working, and you have made a good faith effort at debugging it, then your questions will be much better received. For a beginner, I would recommend going through a barebones tutorial like that at https://www.learn-js.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look through the solution below. I've identified each student by their own class and ID. On the change of an input, I get the class of the input and then run through each of the input values matching the same class. I total these values up and divide by the number of input values entered.

```js
function assignmentGrade(inp) {
  var student = inp.className;
  var studentScores = document.getElementsByClassName(student);
  var totalScore = 0;
  var numberScored = 0;
  var avg = 0;
  if (studentScores) {
    for (var x = 0; x < studentScores.length; x++) {
      if (!isNaN(studentScores[x].value) && studentScores[x].value != "") {
        totalScore = totalScore + parseInt(studentScores[x].value);
        numberScored++;
      }
    }
    //
    if (numberScored > 0) {
      avg = (totalScore / numberScored).toFixed(2);;
      document.getElementById(student).innerHTML = avg;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="gradeTable">
  <!Table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="Header">
      <th>Student Name:</th>
      <th>Student Number:</th>
      <th>Assignment 1 %:</th>
      <th>Assignment 2 %:</th>
      <th>Assignment 3 %:</th>
      <th>Assignment 4 %:</th>
      <th>Assignment 5 %:</th>
      <th>Final Grade %:</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Student A</td>
      <td id="IdenA">172300</td>
      <td><input class="A" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="A" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="A" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="A" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="A" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td id="A"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Student B</td>
      <td id="IdenB">172301</td>
      <td><input class="B" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="B" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="B" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="B" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="B" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td id="B"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Student C</td>
      <td id="IdenC">172302</td>
      <td><input class="C" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="C" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="C" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="C" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td><input class="C" type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="-" onchange="assignmentGrade(this);" /></td>
      <td id="C"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this code is really helpful.  I may have a few questions on how certain parts of it are working later, would you be able to answer them?